# Call PE32+ DLL functions from Python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, dll, usb, ctypes

I have a piece of lab equipment that I'm trying to get data from on a Linux computer.

- The device is  connected by USB and `lsusb` reports the connection as `Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C/D/H Dual UART/FIFO IC`.
- The manufacturer's provided GUI includes a DLL which `file` describes as `PE32+ executable (DLL) (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows, 9 sections`.

The canonical way to get data on Windows is shown in [this driver](https://github.com/QCoDeS/Qcodes/blob/master/qcodes/instrument_drivers/signal_hound/SignalHound_USB_SA124B.py) which uses ctypes.CDLL to interface with the DLL. But if I try to use this code on Linux, I get an errror "invalid ELF header."

Is there a way to use ctypes or a different library like pefile to call the functions provided by this DLL?